# Generating custom pdf layout with Apache PDFBox Library according to a given template?

Tags: java, database, spring, pdf-generation, pdfbox

How can I use the Pdfbox library to generate a custom pdf layout according to a template?

This the template : 
[layout template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6saY.png)

---

I am open to using other libraries as well if it has a more elegant way to achieve the result. The project requires to populate a PDF with the data that is fetched from a database, so it would be helpful if the library can assign `id's` to a particular field in the PDF layout.

**For Eg:** In the attached template, having an `id = fname` for the field `Faculty Name`so that the data from the database can be added to that particular box instead of padding the text.

What I think is ideal for a problem like this is to have a `template.(xml/html)` and a library that can generate a PDF parsing that template with their corresponding `id's`.

---

**Candidate libraries I've found:**

1:[iText7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/)

2:[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

---

**The Stack we're using :**

Front-End : Thymeleaf template engine with bootstrap

Back-End : Spring-Boot,Hibernate.

Database: H2(for testing)

Build-Tool: Maven

---

> Now as you have the problem's context, How can I fetch data from the
>   database and populate the PDF according to the template?

Comment: Let me know if you want more context for the problem.

Comment: Maybe xfdf files? One can also create acroform PDF files in PDFBox with java code but it is quite some work, see e.g. the CreateSimpleForm.java example in the source code download.

Comment: If you want to use `wkhtmltopdf` you will have to create a thymeleaf page like your layout template. You will have to populate value on this page. Then you can generate that html page into pdf .

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks, .xfdf files look promising.

Comment: @AvijitBarua Yeah, that was our last resort. Thanks for the answer though. :)

Comment: Did you generate pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a template to provide the layout is a good approach for several reasons and since you are open to other approaches, you might look at Docmosis.   It uses Word or Libre Office documents as templates and merges with JSON or XML (or other) data.

There's some visual [template examples here](https://www.docmosis.com/resources/examples.html) that give you an idea of how you could take the "layout template" you have shown, draft it into a Word or Libre Office document and use it as a template with Docmosis.

Once your template is designed, you would run it through Docmosis with data to refine the PDF results to what you need.

Please note I work for Docmosis.

I hope that helps.